# Populating a listbox control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a code block that returns a list of employee object.
The resultset contains more than one employee record. One of the elements, is EmployeeID.
I need to populate listview (lstDepartment) with only the EmployeeID. How can I do that?

```
lstDepartment.DataSource = oCorp.GetEmployeeList(emp);
lstDepartment.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to also specify this:

```
     lstDepartment.DataSource = oCorp.GetEmployeeList(emp);
     lstDepartment.DataTextField = "EmployeeID";
     lstDepartment.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
     lstDepartment.DataBind()
```

Comment: A ListView is not a ListBox, it has neither a DataTextField  nor a DataValueField  property.

Comment: My bad @TimSchmelter... my control is a ListBox, not a Listview.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an anonymous type:

```
lstDepartment.DataSource = oCorp.GetEmployeeList(emp)
                                .Select(emp => new { emp.EmployeeID });
lstDepartment.DataBind();
```

**Edit**: But you also could select all columns but diplay only one. A [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdeleting.aspx) is not a `ListBox` or `DropDownList`. Only what you use will be displayed. So if you're ItemTemplate looks like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr runat="server">
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="LblEmployeeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

... only the `EmployeeID` is displayed, no matter whatelse is in your `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

You may mention what to display in your `ItemTemplate` of ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstDepartment" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <p>  <%#Eval("EmployeeID") %> </p>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ah ! I should read better ! Thanks for pointing out in a friendly way : ) Deleting the answer as it is not worth now !